# querystring not passing values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Passing few values through querystring, to testFn() in controller using below code. But in testFn, I am getting null values. When I keep alert on companyName, rdVal,etc. it is showing correct values. but those are not passing to controller. Please let me know what went wrong.

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", null, null, new { id = "lnkSearchMaster", @class = "btn btn-success", onclick = "return lnkgotoAction();" })


function lnkgotoAction() { 
    $('#grdSearchResults').show();
    $('#searchdetails').show();
    var rdVal = $("input[name = SearchType]:checked").attr("id");
    if (rdVal == "CompanyList" || rdVal == "CompanyHistory" || rdVal == "ApplicationSatatus" || rdVal == "Certificates") {

        $('#grdSearchResults').show();
        var companyName = $('#companyname').val();
        var status = $('#status').val();
        var regNo = $('#registrationno').val();
        var appRegNo = $('#applicationrefferenceno').val();

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Search/testFn?test='" + rdVal + "'&companyName='" + $('#companyname').val() +
                    "'&regNum='" + $('#registrationno').val() + "'&appRegNum='" + $('#applicationrefferenceno').val() + "'";
        alert(url);
    }

    $('#grdSearchResults').load(url + ' #grdSearchResults');
    TempData.clear();
    $('#grdSearchResults').show();
    $('#searchdetails').show();

    return false;
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult testFn(string test, string companyName, string regNum, string appRegNum)
    {}
```

Comment: Are you even hitting the controller? Use `$('#grdSearchResults').load('@Url.Action("testFn", "Search")', { test: rdVal, companyName: companyName, regNo: regNo, appRegNum: appRegNum })`.

Comment: Yes it is hitting controller. but the values of the function parameters are null. I tried your code. Still facing the problem. $('#grdSearchResults').load('@Url.Action("testFn", "Search")', { test: rdVal, companyName: companyName, regNo: regNo, appRegNum: appRegNum })

Comment: The the values you are sending are most likely null. Try `console.log({ test: rdVal, companyName: companyName, regNo: regNo, appRegNum: appRegNum });` immediately before `.load()` and check the output

Answer (score -1):

Try as below, it will help you, also always take care the variable name passed to querystring must match controller action parameter names.

```
@Html.Raw(Url.Action("testFn", "Search"), new{ test= rdVal , companyName= companyName , regNum= regNo , appRegNum= appRegNo })
```

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the client. At best this would only post the initial values of the textboxes which is a bit pointless.

Comment: nop, you will get null value if names not match exactly.

Comment: Whats that got to do with it? The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive so `{ name: 'Disha' }`, `{Name: 'Disha' }` and `{nAMe: 'Disha'}` all post back correctly and bind to parameter `string Name`

Comment: I am not talking about case sensitivity but spelling , 'regNo' and  ' regNum',  'appRegNum' and  'appRegNo' will be considered as different names , 'not exactly matched'.

Comment: please un-mark down-vote if you were confused or misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Of course I wont remove it. You code does nothing to solve OP's issue. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view so how could this possibly post back the values from the textboxes. And since OP is posting back using `&appRegNum='" + $('#applicationrefferenceno')` the spelling of the variable is irrelevant (that was only for testing using alerts)

Comment: have you seen the syntax???  it contains "@Html.Raw(Url.Action( " that may help @lavanya b to solve the issue

Comment: What syntax are you talking about. Test your code before posting an answer. Post that line of code into your project and see what you get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69793/discussion-between-disha-and-stephen-muecke).